# PHP - How Compare Decimal Values

Tags: php, decimal

I'm trying figure out how to compare decimal values in PHP properly.

```
$get_decimal_value = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DecimalValue FROM my_table WHERE Id = $some_id LIMIT 1")
or die($db_conn_err);

if(mysqli_num_rows($get_decimal_value) == 1 )
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_decimal_value);
    $my_decimal = $row['DecimalValue'];

    if($my_decimal > 0)
    {
         // IS THIS CORRECT???
         // Does it need to be like '0.00' ?
         // it seems to work both ways...
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: your comparison is fine as is.

Comment: THIS IS CORRECT - What is the Question ?

Comment: @bensiu, Question is inside the if statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is [weakly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_typing), so e.g. `1.0 > 0` should hold no surprises (even things like `1 + "2"` work as *expected*).

Comment: Than you everyone for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. PHP can transform 0 to float without any problems.